# How to import/add an api to an apim in azure via terminalen (Script), NOT from portal?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I use this template, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2019-01-01/service#ApiManagementServiceSkuProperties, and this scrpit,

`az group deployment create -g MyResourceGroup --template-file blank-api.json`

to get a "blank-apim".
But how can import/add an api to this apim? 
I can not use the portal and i have to script evrything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is available](https://twitter.com/darrel_miller/status/964009094792302594) now. See [Api Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2019-01-01/service/apis#apicreateorupdateproperties-object).

```html
{
  "properties": {
    "format": "swagger-link-json",
    "value": "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
    "path": "petstore"
  }
}
```